# CakePHP 3 Component - Request Data or Query being Cleared

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have come across and issue that I need help with. I cannot figure out why this is happening.

I am creating a component in CakePHP that intercepts the data being passed to `/users/login` and depending on the parameter, it acts on it. However, the issue is that, when that data gets there, it is empty. To also note, is that it worked good on remote machines as well as local. The issue started happening when I used `Composer` to upload this plugin into another site. I wonder if the issue is because `Composer` installs the plugin under the `vendor` directory.

This is my code inside the component's `startup method`

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    // ....

    $this->Controller = $this->_registry->getController();

    // ...
}

public function startup(Event $event)
{
    // Here I try to get the [test] parameter that is pass in url
    // http://www.domain.com/users/login?test=testing
    $test = $this->Controller->request->query('test');    
}
```

If I attempt to print the controller request inside the `startup(Event $event)` with `debug($this->Controller->request);` I get the following array:

```
object(Cake\Network\Request) {
    params => [
        'plugin' => null,
        'controller' => 'Users',
        'action' => 'login',
        '_ext' => null,
        'pass' => [],
        'isAjax' => false
    ]
    data => []
    query => []
    url => 'users/login'
    base => ''
    webroot => '/'
    here => '/users/login'
    trustProxy => false
    [protected] _environment => [
        'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => '/var/www/domain.com/website/webroot/index.php',
        'SCRIPT_NAME' => '/index.php',
        'REQUEST_URI' => '/users/login?test=testing',
        'DOCUMENT_URI' => '/index.php',
```

The `REQUEST_URI` shows clearly that `test` is being passed.

What could be causing CakePHP not to take in the `test` parameter when it was installed using `Composer`? Why is `params['pass'] => []`, `data => []` and `query => []` empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trying to figure this out, it had to take my 8-year old daughter to point me out in the right direction. A simple, but time-wasting, head-scratching mistake that was causing all the issues. The issue was located inside my NGINX configuration file.

I had the following:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;
}
```

but I should have had the following:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Because I had ommitted the `?` after `index.php`, NGINX was simply not taking any parameters that were passed in the url.

Lesson learned!